# Spring Boot project - CSS Autocomplete not working in STS 4.7

Tags: css, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I am developing web application with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf as template engine. I've placed all CSS files at "resource/static/css" location. But when i try to edit html file, STS doesn't suggest CSS classes from both my custom CSS file and bootstrap CSS file. Have tried all settings like checking editors code suggestion in preference, adding code proposal in editors. Still no luck.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzmtt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Related discussion on the project GitHub issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/510